# Java Reflections Library - Class loader warnings about unrelated classes

Tags: java, reflection

I'm using the [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) to get all classes annotated by a specific annotation in a specific package.

**IndexSpec annotation**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface IndexSpec {
    String value();
}
```

**Annotated class**

```
@IndexSpec("connected_clients")
public class ConnectedClients implements ElasticIndex {
    [...]
}
```

**Reflection**

```
[...]

var reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("a.b.c.indices")) // Package name redacted for legal reasons
        .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(), new TypeAnnotationsScanner()));

var annotatedIndices = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(IndexSpec.class);

[...]
```

This code works fine but I get a large amount of warnings. There is are a few hundred of them for many of different, unrelated classes.

Reflections says it found a lot of classes in a package that contains exactly two classes.

```
Reflections took 2303 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 2898 keys and 11715 values
```

The warnings all look like this:

```
[org.reflections.Reflections] could not get type for name com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper from any class loader
```

Why is the library scanning classes in a different package than what it was configured for?

Comment: I guess it's scanning everything on the classpath?

Comment: You didn’t restrict the scan to a package. You requested to scan all class path entries containing a matching package.

Comment: Huh, I thought the setUrls() would restrict the scan to only that package. How do I restrict the scan to only this package?

Comment: I don’t use this library and the documentation is……very disc space efficient. There are `ConfigurationBuilder.setInputsFilter(…)` and `FilterBuilder.includePackage(…)`…